Mid 2000s horror comedy where the monsters can sense sin
I remember watching a movie on tv a few years ago, and can't remember the title, only a few details.
It has two male leads, and a female. And I'm pretty sure there's a red car.
Towards the end the girl gets captured by monsters/demons, and the two guys go to rescue her, but the monsters/demons can sense sin, so they have to go to confession and confess everything in their lives.
At the end I'm pretty sure the two guys end up chatting in a diner and then the girl shows up again.
Sounds a bit sketchy, but that's all I got. If you could help out with the title I'd appreciate it. I think it's a relatively low budget movie, if that helps.

Can you provide more details, such as: Where did you see it - cable, network TV; Age or description of the actors; Language; Was it a comedy, thriller, or horror. As the question stands now, there isn't much information to identify it, especially when you consider how many low-budget cable movies are shown each year. A few more details can help a lot.

Possibly horror comedy Soulkeeper from 2001. From TVTropes:

the two [male] thief protagonists are pitted against Simon Magus, an Evil Sorcerer who specializes in corrupting souls. A spirit ally tells the two that they need to cleanse their souls to avoid being corrupted by Magus. So they go to a confessional and confess every sin they ever committed in their entire lives. The priest needs aspirin by the time they are done. 

Here's the trailer (slightly NSFW):



